# "Runtime error 91" when opening documents in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, runtime-error

When I open a Word document from my desktop or from an e-mail, I get the following error message

> Runtime error 91: Object variable or with block variable not set

If I open Word from the `Program Files\Microsoft Office` I don't get the error. I checked all my add-ins, comparing with my other PC, and they're exactly the same.

How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Does the document you're opening contain macros?

Comment: not that i am aware of